# Scala: How to include other conf files from other directories in base config file?

Tags: java, scala, typesafe-config

I have a Scala app with a base config file, `local.conf`. It is getting a bit large, so I want to split it up and I want to have those parts located in a child directory `src/main/resources/local`. Adding the include to the `local.conf` doesn't work. It errors about not finding the resulting config keys. Why doesn't `include` allow me to add files from other directories? How to fix?

**Folder Structure**

```
src->main->resources:
application.conf
local.conf
prod.conf
local/more_config.conf
prod/more_config.conf
```

**local.conf**

```
include "secrets.conf"
include "local/more_config.conf"

myApp ${localConfig} {
    buildEnv: "local"
}
```

**local/more_config.conf**

```
localConfig {
    mysqlConfig {
        user: "blah",
        password: "blah",
        host: "localhost:3306"
    }
}
```

**Error:** `Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${localConfig}`

However, if I move the `more_config.conf` file to the same resources directory and change my include, it works fine... ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Using https://github.com/lightbend/config

Why is this? How to fix?

Comment: Which library are you using for configuration ?

Comment: @GaëlJ It seems we are using https://github.com/lightbend/config

Comment: Have you tried the `include file(...)` syntax?